# how to show cutom error page in node js with http, url and fs module without express module

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to **call index.html when someone enters localhost:3000/index.html**, **contact-me.html when someone enter localhost:3000/contact-me.html** and **404.html when someone enters something else** in node js project.

**Please note i am not using express js module, just simply http, fs and url module**

Below is the code snippet for the same.

**index.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');

//creating the server and listening on port 3000
http.createServer(function (req, res){
  var path =  url.parse(req.url, true);
  var filename = "." + path.pathname;
  console.log(filename);
  fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
    if(err){
      console.log("inside error");
      fs.readFile('404.html', function(err, data){
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write("Hello world");
        return res.end();
      });
    }
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    return res.end();
  });
}).listen(3000);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>This is index html page</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**contact-me.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>This is contact me page</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**404.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>This is 404 error page</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

but when i enter http://localhost:3000/blahblab.html its giving below error

```
_http_outgoing.js:670
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('first argument',
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer. Received undefined
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:670:11)
    at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:638:15)
    at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Users\jharo\Music\frontendMasters_beginners\odinproject\projectone\index.js:20:9)
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:261:13) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

Comment: Simply load the page of `index.html` as you are already if the req URL is `!=` to the three values you mentioned, else, respond with the other page. So I am assuming something with if `(path.pathname != 'index.html' || path.pathname != 'contact-me.html') { }`, etc...

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, its correct but don't you think its just a workaround to ge the solution since **fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {}** provides err parameter to work on when fileName is not present, we should use it right ?

Comment: I will try and get on a computer to actually write you some code, I did this without coding anything. If I have some time.